# Inserting filter between custom source and SmartTee leaks COM object

Tags: c++, windows, com, directshow

We have a DirectShow graph consisting of our own Source filter which is rendered using the CaptureGraphBuilder. In preview mode the graph results in [Source] -> [SmartTee] -(PreviewPin)-> [Decoder] -> [Renderer]. Our own filter has an custom allocator and notifies the SmartTee about it. Exiting now will be fine, all objects get released.

Now we are trying to insert a filter between our own source filter and the SmartTee filter. When connecting the newly created filter to our source filter a new allocator is created at the source filter. When connecting the new filter (which would propose a custom allocator on the output pin itself) to the SmartTee filter the SmartTee proposes the allocator which was created in the first connection between source and SmartTee. But the SmartTee should have dropped this allocator due to the BreakConnect. Exiting the application now results in one remaining source allocator object which is the allocator created in the first connection.

The source filter, as well as the inserted filter have an InitAllocator function on the output pin to propose the allocator.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the source of DecideAllocator function in CBaseOutputPin class. The output pin selects an allocator. It can use one provided by the input pin, or create its own: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390924(v=vs.85).aspx
In order to do that the CBaseOutputPin calls GetAllocator of the input pin and determines if the input provides it's own allocator.
To provide an allocator for an output pin, override the CBaseOutputPin::InitAllocator method to create an instance of your allocator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377477(v=vs.85).aspx
At this point your allocator should be used and the outpin calls IMemInputPin::NotifyAllocator to inform the input pin of the selection. If NotifyAllocator returns an error then the allocator is Released. 
Have you based your output pin on CBaseOutputPin and have you replaced the DecideAllocator method?

Comment: I tried it, it seems to work if i'm not overriding the allocator proposed by video renderer (this allocator negotiation is done in a custom base class). but sadly this just works for preview mode. in case of capture and preview it won't remove the leak.

Comment: It might be a leak inside your allocator.

Comment: well of course, because the allocator is not released as the ref count doen't reach zero.